# Проверить правильность построения xsd схемы

Tags: xml, xsd

Впервые столкнулся с XML, составил схему и при попытке проверить ее через онлайн-переводчики выдает ошибку, никак не могу разобраться что ему не нравится.
(Element http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:simpleType is invalid in this context.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="A" type="Home"/>

<xs:complexType name="Home">
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B" type="letter" maxOccurs="5" minOccurs="0"/>        
        <xs:element name="D" type="letter" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="0"/>         
     </xs:sequence>          
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="letter">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[A-Fa-f]{1}"/>
            </xs:restriction> 
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="C" type="Ctype" use="required"/>         
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="Ctype">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Прошу помощи в указании в чем ошибка и желательно как ее исправить, или хотя бы подсказки в нужном направлении. По заданию схему необходимо составить по имеющемуся xml.

```
<A>
<B C="1234">d</B>
<B C="4211">b</B>
<B C="0312">b</B>
<B C="1543">d</B>
<B C="2345">b</B>
<D C="1233">d</D>
<D C="4321">b</D>
</A>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта схема в точности валидирует ваш xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="A" type="Home"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Home">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="B" type="letter" maxOccurs="5" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="D" type="letter" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="letter">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="letterType">
        <xs:attribute name="C" type="Ctype" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="letterType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[A-Fa-f]{1}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="Ctype">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```